# Can you omit "which was" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, whiz-deletion

For example:

"The song, which was released in 1982, has since become a hit."

"The song, released in 1982, has since become a hit."

Do these two sentences mean the same thing, and are they both grammatically correct?

Comment: Yes/yes, and I would not change the word order.

Answer (score 1):

Both mean the same thing, but I would just say

> The song has become a hit since its release in 1982.